# How are "salmon mesh" made?

Tags: salmon

I heard in British Columbia, sometimes salmon are made into mesh-like meat product that looks like the following:
[image]

How are they made?

Comment: Where is the picture from?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the image you are showing is of fresh-caught salmon which is on racks being air dryed or smoked. The pattern you see are cuts made in the flesh to aid in the process. The [Alaska Department of Fish and Game has an information sheet](http://www.npafc.org/new/publications/Newsletter/NL36/Newsletter36%20(46-47).pdf) on smoking and drying fish.

Cutting is done so that the fish will dry quickly by exposing as much surface area as possible to the air. In Alaska, a traditional method is to cut the flesh away from the backbone, scoring it so that folds of flesh hang exposed to the air.

This method of fish drying has a strong tradition among the peoples in the Pacific Northwest within Canada's First Nation and Alaska's Native Communities, with each group having its own unique cutting technique. This [University of Alaska at Anchorage publication](http://www.ankn.uaf.edu/publications/vs/cutting.html) has an excellent overview of the process of cutting and drying fish.